# SQL Query taking too long to execute in VS2012 but instantly in MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, telerik-reporting

Suddenly, some querys that I have in a Winforms app are taking too long to execute directly in the code but when I copy the query and execute it in MSSQL it takes 0.02 ms. I can't figure out what is going on. This happens not in all my SQL querys and I can't understand if there's a pattern or a logic behind that. Have you already face something like this?

Comment: **[`Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries`](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)**

Comment: can you show us the query..? also can you show how your are executing the code in C#, perhaps you have network issues.. this can be any number of things.. perhaps the query is not optimized .. Indexes...etc

Comment: this morning everything went ok with this query, it's a SP that calls a Function, everything is opitimized. I've already readed the article suggested above, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, it turns out that MSSQL uses a different plan than applications build in visual studio.

I ran this query to make all my connections use the same plan, it worked for me.

```
declare @value sql_variant

select @value = SESSIONPROPERTY('ARITHABORT') 
if @value <> 1 
begin 
  USE master 
  ALTER DATABASE [yourDataBaseName] SET ARITHABORT ON WITH NO_WAIT 
use yourDataBaseName
```

end

Comment: The article "Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries" clearly says not to set ARITHABORT ON. Why would you suggest this answer? I'm also facing the same problem and trying to find a solution for it, but your answer is something that the article's author says not to do